# How to install python in a docker image?

Tags: python, docker

I want to create a docker image with `selenium` and `chrome` correctly installed, so I choose a base image with these properties. Therefore, the first line of the `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM selenium/node-chrome:3.7.1-argon
```

Then the next command is

```
RUN apt-get update
```

which created the following error while creating the docker image:

```
Step 4/19 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in af08ae07cbf3
Reading package lists...
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

How to be able to install `python` in this docker image?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`RUN apt-get update`

`RUN apt-get install -y python3`

As hinted by:

> Acquire (13: Permission denied)

I believe this is due to your base image:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/NodeChrome/Dockerfile

As you can see it swaps from the default user context of 'root' to 'seluser'.

You can either:

1. wear this as a consequence of the base image (i.e. use sudo)
2. swap back: `USER root`
3. or consider creating your own docker image to avoid swapping in the first place

Using `sudo` is best avoided in Dockerfiles where possible, so it would be preferable to go with option #2 or #3, rather than #1.

Hope that helps mate.

Comment: Yes. Strange. I created a docker image before and never required 'root'...

Comment: Well the only reason it would make sense is if you used the 'USER' directive, otherwise I would assume the container should be of user root and thus not need sudo.

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify, there is in the base image you are inheriting from.

Comment: One thing to notice this installs python 2. As I can see you're doing stuff with `selenium` and `chrome`, you may want to install python 3 to make it work.

Comment: In the event that you need a particular version of python, for example python 2.7, you can type `RUN sudo apt-get install python2.7`.

Answer (score 14):

**Note:** Below commands may require root/administrative previleges.

1. Download docker image `docker pull ubuntu`
2. Start interactive container `docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash`

**Note:** By default you will be logged in inside container as root user if not then either elevate your privileges to root or use `sudo` before below listed commands

3. Update container instance `apt-get update`
4. For python 2.7 `apt-get install python2`
5. For Python 3.x `apt-get install python3`

Comment: when you do `apt-get install python` which one do you install?

Comment: @KansaiRobot it appears that `apt-get install python` used to install Python 2 but has since been removed to force the user to be more explicit: `Package python is not available, but is referred to by another package. [...] However the following packages replace it: [...] python2 [...] E: Package 'python' has no installation candidate`. 

Where `[...]` is me removing unnecessary text.

Answer (score 2):

First, you would like to log in as root:

```
sudo docker exec -u root -it 88d53df8fd19 /bin/bash
```

Once you are there, you will be root and will be able to run commands as such without problems.

Run below command inside container to install python

```
apt update
apt-get install python3.6
```

Comment: The question was about how to create a Docker image. Your command can be used to log into a running container and modify the container, not the image.