# dockerfile to install mysql and run scripts inside the ubuntu image

Tags: python, mysql, docker, ubuntu

How can we create a simple docker file that can run mysql database and execute scripts present in some folder 
 like **scripts-folder**, 
 then run python application which will use this mysql database internally.
 
 
Currently, I have a Dockerfile to create mysql docker image and run scripts on it, but i don't want to create a seperate docker image for database work.

```
# Derived from official mysql image (our base image)
FROM mysql
# Add a database
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE mydatabase
# Add the content of the sql-scripts/ directory to your image
# All scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ are automatically
# executed during container startup
COPY ./sql-scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

But, I need to have only 1 ubuntu docker image that should run both mysql and python application internally.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

Comment: normally you need to create two container on for python and one for mysql. or you can use sqlite simply in python docker

Comment: please see the question, i don't want separate containers.

Comment: I know, therefore I wrote use sqlite, or show us what did you already try , what the error you got.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines

```
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install python
COPY <path/to/your/script.py>
CMD [ "python3", "script.py" ]
```

More information:

[Dockerize python app](https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-python-application)

[Install python into a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216784/how-to-install-python-in-a-docker-image/47216866)

Comment: i don't want to create a seperate docker image for database work.

Comment: I know, this is why i didn't tell you to create a new dockerfile, i told you to ADD the lines into your mysql dockerfile.

Comment: are you telling me to build a mysql image and add python code mysql image, is that your answer???

Comment: I'm telling you to build your image with the requirements to run your python application, your docker image is probably a unix-like system, meaning you can access the shell inside and do whatever you want, the MySQL database is just one thing running, you can run more them one if your image has the everything it needs

Comment: Sir, i have tried that but mysql image is not a server hosting image, so runs the API but don't host it as well as mysql is not connecting.