# Installing Python 3.11.1 on a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I want to use `debian:bullseye` as a base image and then install a specific Python version - i.e. 3.11.1.  At the moment I am just learning docker and linux.

From what I understand I can either:

1. Download and compile sources
2. Install binaries (using apt-get)
3. Use a Python base image

I have come across countless questions on here and articles online.  Do I use [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/nightly/+packages)?  What version do I need?  Are there any official python distributions ([who is deadsnakes anyway](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398568/installing-python-who-is-deadsnakes-and-why-should-i-trust-them))?

But ultimately I want to know the best means of getting Python on there.  I don't want to use a Python base image - I am curious in the steps involved.  Compile sources - I am far from having that level of knowhow - and one for another day.

Currently I am rolling with the following:

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository "ppa:deadsnakes/ppa"
RUN apt install python3.11
```

This fails with:

```
#8 1.546 E: Unable to locate package python3.11
#8 1.546 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.11'
```

Ultimately - it's not the error - its just finding a good way of getting a specific Python version on my container.

Comment: Does [How to install Python in a Docker image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216784) answer the question?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - unfortunately not as that will install a latest Python 3.x.  I want a specific version - "finding a good way of getting a specific Python version".  So at some point I can control getting Python 3.12 on there - when I decide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you want to install Python 3.11 in debian bullseye you have to compile it from source following the next steps (inside the Dockerfile):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common wget
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/Python-3.11.1.tar.xz
sudo tar -xf Python-3.11.1.tar.xz
cd Python-3.11.1
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

---

Another option (easiest) would be to use the official Python Docker image, in your case:

```
FROM 3.11-bullseye
```

You have all the versions available in [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python).

Other option that could be interesting in your case is `3.11-slim-bullseye`, that is an image that does not contain the common packages contained in the default tag and only contains the minimal packages needed to run python.

Comment: I don't want to use a base Python image - I want to control installation myself on `debian:bullseye`.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to complete my answer

Comment: Why would this fail on `./configure --enable-optimizations` with the error `./configure: not found`

Comment: So I discovered that concatenating the commands, as done in @Andez answer below, resolved the failure. In other words: `RUN cd /usr/src \
    && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/Python-3.11.0.tgz \
    && tar -xzf Python-3.11.0.tgz \
    && cd Python-3.11.0 \
    && ./configure --enable-optimizations \
    && make altinstall`

Comment: @Shawn You probably ran into this error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19816655/3566606

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@tomasborella answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75159858/405022), to do this in docker:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get -y install build-essential \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libncurses5-dev \
        libgdbm-dev \ 
        libnss3-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        libbz2-dev \
        wget \
    && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get purge -y imagemagick imagemagick-6-common 

RUN cd /usr/src \
    && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.0/Python-3.11.0.tgz \
    && tar -xzf Python-3.11.0.tgz \
    && cd Python-3.11.0 \
    && ./configure --enable-optimizations \
    && make altinstall

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.11 1
```

`update-alternatives` - will update the links to allow you to run `python` as opposed to specifying `python3.11` when you want to run it.

It takes a while to compile those sources!

Comment: for some reason, those commands like wget when building the docker file doesnt not do anything. if i shell into the container and execute them manually, they work.  any thoughts why that may be?

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 22.04

You can do:

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Minsk
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt install python3.11 python3-pip -y
```